# Create collection from another collection

Tags: c#

I have a collection of objects with 3 properties

```
public class Match
{
    public string ReleaseNumber { get; set; }
    public string UnitNumber { get; set; }
    public float ConfidenceProbability { get; set; }
}

public class MatchReply
{
    public IEnumerable<Match> Matches { get; set; }
}
```

and I would like to create a new collection where the object is similar to the original in that it has the same properties minus one, i.e.

```
public class Release
{
    public string ReleaseNumber { get; set; }
    public float ConfidenceProbability { get; set; }
}

public class EventMessage
{
    public IEnumerable<Release> Releases { get; set; }
}
```

I thought of copying the collection, iterating through it and removing a property from each object - but this is more what I would do in Python. I also thought that I could create an extension of `Match` that I could call e.g. `Match.ToRelease()` but I can't figure out exactly how to apply it to the original collection.

What is the C# way of doing this?

Comment: You could try `Automapper` for that. This is effectively what you're about to do: mapping objects to another objects.

Comment: Do you actually need copies or do you just want to hide the property `UnitNumber`? If the latter, you could easily use an interface and `Cast<T>()` extension method.

Comment: thanks @dymanoid, will try

Comment: @Fildor I need to take this collection and put it inside a data model that I defined to publish messages into a message bus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use LINQ for this.

```
private static IEnumerable<Match> getMatchList()
{
    List<Match> matchList = new List<Match>();

    matchList.Add(new Match {
        ConfidenceProbability = 1.0f,
        ReleaseNumber = "RELEASE#1",
        UnitNumber = "UNIT1"
    });

    matchList.Add(new Match
    {
        ConfidenceProbability = 2.0f,
        ReleaseNumber = "RELEASE#2",
        UnitNumber = "UNIT2"
    });

    return matchList;
}
```

```
var matchList = getMatchList();

var releaseList = matchList.Select(r => new Release {
    ConfidenceProbability = r.ConfidenceProbability,
    ReleaseNumber = r.ReleaseNumber
}).ToList();
```